# NHIbernate Conditional projection queries

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria, nhibernate-projections

I have requirement, wherein I have to calculate totals for cash and credit cards separately using conditional projection queries. My below code doesnt work and it gives me datatype mismatch error. Its says the true condition returns decimal and false returns currency. I am not sure why it does that as 0.0M does represent decimal. Can anybody please help me out with the query?

```
RefundTemplate.Criteria.SetProjection(
                        Projections.ProjectionList()

                        .Add(Projections.Sum(Projections.Conditional
                            (Restrictions.Eq("PaymentType", "CK"),
                                  Projections.Property("Gross"), Projections.Constant(0.0M))), "CashRefund")
                        .Add(Projections.Sum(Projections.Conditional
                            (Restrictions.Eq("PaymentType", "CC"),
                                  Projections.Property("Gross"), Projections.Constant(0.0M))), "CreditRefund"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify explicitly which type to use. For example:

```
Projections.Constant(0.0M, NHibernateUtil.Decimal)
```

See the documentation for the `NHibernateUtil` class here: http://elliottjorgensen.com/nhibernate-api-ref/NHibernate/NHibernateUtil.html

Comment: In my case i required to cast string....

    Projections.Conditional
                        (
                            Restrictions.IsNotNull(Projections.Property(() => model.Name)),
                            Projections.Cast(NHibernateUtil.String, Projections.Property(() => model.Name)),
                            Projections.Constant(string.Empty, NHibernateUtil.String)
                        ),